# How to display globe view (3D view) of Maps in Xamarn.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We need to show selected cities on 3D map of earth in Android, iOS & Windows.UWP using Xamarin.Forms. Currently we are using Xamarin.Forms.Maps, but it only shows 2D map of earth.

How do we go for 3D map of earth?

Note: We will require zoom-in feature of map as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something like Google Earth you're probably going to have to create your own implementation. What you can do in Xamarin Forms however is use the existing `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` controls and add what's called a camera. Basically this is a viewpoint from which you look upon the map. These can be in 3D space so it looks like you have a 3D map. You can create this using custom renderers.

Within these custom renderers you will come across things like pitch, heading and distance. This image show what's what:

[image]

**iOS custom renderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Map3d), typeof(MapView3dRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MapView3dRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        MKMapView _nativeMap;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
            {
                _nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (_nativeMap == null)
                return;

            if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion")
                UpdateCameraView();
        }

        void UpdateCameraView()
        {
            var target = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(50.890119f, 5.857798f);

            //Enable 3D buildings
            _nativeMap.ShowsBuildings = true;
            _nativeMap.PitchEnabled = true;

            // Attach the camera
            var camera = MKMapCamera.CameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate(target, 650, 60, 0);
            _nativeMap.Camera = camera;
        }
    }
}
```

**Android**

For Android I don't have a custom renderer ready but you should be able to figure it out. It also involves attaching a `Camera` object. This time you add it to an instance of `GoogleMap`.

```
// Create the camera
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                  .Target(location)
                                                  .Tilt(45)
                                                  .Zoom(10)
                                                  .Bearing(0)
                                                  .Build();
// Convert to an update object
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

// Attach the camera
map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate); // map is of type GoogleMap
```

Check out the [Android docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#the_camera_position) on how this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however we need to show pins on certain cities over the spherical map (globe) of earth. We don't require to zoom-in to the level where we can see 3D \ tilted street view.